# Libgdx project generation

Tags: android, libgdx

Whenever I try to create a project using libgdx.jar it says I need to have the latest Android API 28 but my SDK manager says I already have it.

Can anyone suggest what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to point the setup application to your sdk location. I recommend using [this one](https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-setup) instead, it allows you to set the sdk location in the app.